# Logical value of CPLEX constraint

Tags: constraints, cplex

A C++ CPLEX model that I have is long, and I build constraints inside functions. Say I have a function that returns a constraint:

```
IloConstraint f(IloInt i, IloInt j, IloNumVarArray x)
{
    IloConstraint constr;
    constr = (x[j]-x[i] >= 15)  && (x[j]-x[i] <= 20);
    return constr;
}
```

Is it possible to do pass a constant array instead of a variable array *x*, and to obtain a logical value of constraint, i.e. to do something like.

```
IloNumArray a(env, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
IloConstraint c = f(1,2,a);
cout<<c.logicalValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IloAnd

In CPLEX documentation you can read

```
For example, you may write:

 IloAnd and(env);
 and.add(constraint1);
 and.add(constraint2);
 and.add(constraint3);
 

Those lines are equivalent to :

 IloAnd and = constraint1 && constraint2 && constraint3;
```

Comment: I don't think that this answers the original question. It's not about constructing constraints, it is about testing whether a specific set of values satisfies a constraint or not. I don't think that you can do that directly with CPLEX,

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick That is right, I asked "whether a specific set of values satisfies a constraint or not".

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a real solution, but I have some workaround. Assuming we already have a constraint *c*, we create a new model with *c* as its constraint, and add new bounds for the variables.

```
bool constraintLogicalValue(IloConstraint const& constr, IloEnv env,  IloNumVarArray const& x, IloNumArray const& a, unsigned int const n)
{        
    IloModel model(env);
    IloCplex cplex_model(model);
    cplex_model.setOut(env.getNullStream());

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        model.add(x[i]==a[i]);

    model.add(constr);
    return(cplex_model.solve());
}
```

Now we can use it in the following way:

```
int n;
IloEnv env;
IloModel model(env);
IloNumVarArray x (env);
...
IloNumArray a(env);
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    a.add(1);

IloConstraint c = f(1,2,x);
cout<<constraintLogicalValue(c, env, x, a, n);
```

EDIT: A problem could be an existing bounds for *x*, which are passed into *constraintLogicalValue()*. If *x[i]==a[i]* is out of these bonds, for some *i*, the model is unfeasible and we obtain *false* as a result, event if *constr* is satisfied.

Sometimes this is what we want.

Comment: Glad you found a way to do this. I am curious about why you want to do this. It would be more efficient to write your 'checker' not usng the Cplex variables and constraints, and I have done exactly this on previous projects. Having the code written twice in two different ways can be a useful extra check that the results are good.

Comment: I have disagreement between cplex model and heuristics, so I assumethere is a mistake in cplex. I have complicate structure of a various constraints, and the problem is among constraints that are satisfiable. So, i need to detect those.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Do you think that your cplex model is not the same as intended? Does it find 'solutions' that should not be allowed, or does it not find solutions that you found using heuristics or similar and believe are OK? Have you tried saving your CPLEX model as an LP file? You can always try forcing a known solution into your CPLEX model e.g. by adding constraints to fix the values of most or all of your variables. That may show you more information. You can also try using the infeasibility checker to find an 'irreducible infeasible' subset of your problem and that can also help.